# Importing custom angular library

Tags: angular

I've created an angular library which I published to custom npm repository in Azure DevOps.

I've installed the package into my angular project. When I want to import the module from the library into the app.module.ts I get the error bellow.

Can anyone help me to resolve it?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵmod')
    at getNgModuleDef (core.mjs:1137:1)
    at recurse (core.mjs:21765:1)
    at recurse (core.mjs:21776:1)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.mjs:21761:1)
    at new NgModuleFactory (core.mjs:21883:1)
    at compileNgModuleFactory (core.mjs:25865:1)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.mjs:26096:1)
    at Module.4431 (main.ts:12:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at __webpack_exec__ (main.ts:13:39)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Please share a minimal and reproductible project where we can see your error.

Comment: How do you try to import it and can u share the dependencies in package?

Comment: The problem was that I was not publishing the compiled version from 'dist/my-lib'. When I published it from there all worked well.